# Draw Checkerboard on Python

Tags: python

I want to draw a checkerboard on Python, but I only get one black square.
Can you help me fix this program?

```
import turtle
def filled_square(size, color, x, y):
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
       angle = 90
       turtle.fd(size)
       turtle.lt(angle)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.up()
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])
s = int(sys.argv[2])
square_size = s//n
y=0
for i in range(n):
    x = 0
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
           filled_square(square_size, "red", x, y)
        else:
           filled_square(square_size, "black", x, y)
    x+=square_size
turtle.down()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Comment: I fixed my code.

Comment: Good effort :-) but it's still not quite right. I'm getting an IndentationError on the `x = 0` line. (you might be thinking "well that's pretty easy for you to just fix yourself, right?" and that's true, but I would really like to be completely sure what the original indentation is. Because it definitely matters how much indentation your `x+=square_size` line has, and we can't unambiguously deduce that from context)

Comment: Use i and j to fill the squares?

Comment: I refixed my code. And I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
y=0
for i in range(n):
    x = 0
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
           filled_square(square_size, "red", x, y)
        else:
           filled_square(square_size, "black", x, y)
    x+=square_size
```

Couple problems here.

- There's not much point in increasing the value of x when you reset it right back to zero in the next iteration, so the initial assignment should be above the for loop.
- you never update the value of y.

```
x = 0
for i in range(n):
    y=0
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
           filled_square(square_size, "red", x, y)
        else:
           filled_square(square_size, "black", x, y)
        y+=square_size
    x+=square_size
```

Now you should get the checkerboard shape you want.

[image]

---

Alternate solution: you can avoid the problem of bookkeeping the values of x and y by not having those values at all. You can derive the coordinates of the squares straight from i and j.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
            filled_square(square_size, "red", i*square_size, j*square_size)
        else:
            filled_square(square_size, "black", i*square_size, j*square_size)
```

It might also be nice to consolidate the common logic in your if and else blocks, and only differentiate the values that actually change (namely, the color)

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
            color = "red"
        else:
            color = "black"
        filled_square(square_size, color, i*square_size, j*square_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment both x and y. Also note that x should be incremented in the inner loop. Here is the working code,

```
import turtle
def filled_square(size, color, x, y):
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        angle = 90
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.lt(angle)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.up()
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])
s = int(sys.argv[2])
square_size = s//n
y=0
for i in range(n):
    x = 0
    for j in range(n):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
            filled_square(square_size, "red", x, y)
        else:
            filled_square(square_size, "black", x, y)
        x+=square_size
    y+=square_size
turtle.down()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using functional programming like this for board/game work. It'll make everything easier to maintain and make implementing new features easier.

```
import turtle

def filled_square(size, color, x, y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        angle = 90
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.lt(angle)
    turtle.end_fill()

def board(length, size, x_pos=0, y_pos=0):
    for y in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if (x+y)%2==0:
                filled_square(
                    size,  "red", (x * square_size) - x_pos, (y * square_size) - y_pos)
            else:
                filled_square(
                    size, "black", (x * square_size) - x_pos, (y * square_size) - y_pos)
    turtle.done()
```

Keyword arguments are great too. If you decided you wanted to add more colors, it is as easy as adding an two parameters,

```
def board(length, size, x_pos=0, y_pos=0, color1="red", color2="black"):
    for y in range(length):
        for x in range(length):
            if (x+y)%2==0:
                filled_square(
                    size,  color1, (x * square_size) - x_pos, (y * square_size) - y_pos)
            else:
                filled_square(
                    size, color2, (x * square_size) - x_pos, (y * square_size) - y_pos)
```